# Restricting Available Drop Down Values

Tags: acumatica

I have a customer who would like to remove the "Credit Adj." and "Prepayment" options on the "Bills and Adjustments (AP301000)" screen.

I created a Customization Project and looked at the Attributes on the Type field. It looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know if it's possible to add some code to the "Customize Attributes" area of the above screenshot to hide the "Credit Adj." and "Prepayment" options?

Comment: You need to make your own version of the APMigrationModeDependentInvoiceTypeList with the list of the items you want. I don't think you can hide from an existing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create your own ListAttribute and then replace the one for APInvoice.DocType.

Example ListAttribute

```cs
using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.AP;

namespace APDocTypeOverride {
    public class APPaymentDocTypeExt {
        public new class ListAttribute : PXStringListAttribute {
            public ListAttribute () : base (
                new string[] { APDocType.Invoice, APDocType.DebitAdj },
                new string[] { Messages.Invoice, Messages.DebitAdj }) { ; }
        }
    }
}
```

After that you would need to replace the attribute on the DocType field. You can do that by either overriding the DocType attribute on the DAC or by just overriding the screen using the CacheAttached event. I would override the screen otherwise doing it at the DAC level would override every screen in Acumatica that uses it.

Example APInvoiceEntry graph extention

```cs
[PXDBString(3, IsKey = true, IsFixed = true)]
[PXDefault]
[APDocTypeOverride.APPaymentDocTypeExt.List]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Type", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Enabled = true, TabOrder = 0)]
[PXFieldDescription]
protected virtual void APInvoice_DocType_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{

}
```